A bidirectional one-to-one association on a foreign key is common with many-to-one issue
[tag:`XML Approach
<class name="Campaign">
    <id name="id" column="cmp_num">
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="person" property-ref="address" cascade="all"/>   
</class>

<class name="MopChangeDocData">
    <id name="id" column="mop_cd_data_id">
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="campaign" column="cmp_id" unique="true"/>   
</class>

Table
mop_change_doc_data
With the xml approach application works fine and generates the expected data but with the annotation approach it does not fetching the data.
Annotation Classes
@Entity
@Table(name="parent_cmp")
public class Campaign {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cmp_num", referenceColumnName="mop_cd_data_id")
    private MopChangeDocData mopChangeDocData;
    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="mop_change_doc_data")
public class MopChangeDocData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional="false")
    @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id")
    private Campaign campaign;
    // getters and setters
}

I ran both programs, with xml approach it fetches both tables data eg.
select columns..,.. from parent_cmp this_ left out join mop_change_doc_data mop on this_.cmp_num = mop.cmp_id where conditions....
but with the annotation approach its just fetches only parent_cmp data e.g.
select columns...., from parent_cmp this_ where conditions...
Please help me on this how can I achieve the same output from the xml in annotation based classes`]
